# These basic combinatorial questions make me confused

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we throw two dice. How many many combinations we have?

Most of the books (if not all), answer this question saying:

$$6\times 6= 36$$

In the probability books when asked about the chances to get a particular combination of the dice:

$$\frac{1}{6}\times \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$$

The coins have the same the same reasoning.

Unless the dice are colored, the dice are equal.  So in my view $(2,1)$ is the same as $(1,2)$.

Sometimes I have a troubles to interpret similar questions but with balls. Anyone could give me some tips to help me how to interpret these kind of questions when the author isn't enough explicit?

Comment: The reason people often say $36$ is because those $36$, with $(1,2)\neq (2,1)$ are all equi-probable.  That makes the analysis a lot simpler.  If you prefer to say that $(a,b)=(b,a)$ then you have $21$ possible outcomes but $\{1,2\}$, say, is twice as probable as $\{1,1\}$.

Comment: @lulu good enough to be an actual answer tbh

Comment: @lulu so we are answering wrongly just to get an easier calculation?

Comment: No,  Why would you say that?  There are $36$ ordered pairs, which are equally probable, and $21$ unordered pairs that are not.  The two counts answer two (slightly) different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case of two (fair) coins, because its easier to list the results.

When we distinguish the order of the coins, we have **four** *equally probably outcomes*: $$\sf\{(T,T),(T,H),(H,T),(H,H)\}$$

When we do not distinguish the order of the coins, we have **three** outcomes, but *one is twice as probable* as each of the others (the coins remain distinct objects, even when an observer cannot identify which is which) : $$\sf\{TT,TH,HH\}$$

It is *not wrong* to identify events as collections of atoms each with differing probability weights, but we *prefer* to identify events as collections of *equally probable atoms* whenever possible, because then the probability of an event is proportional to the count for its atoms.  It just makes things easier to calculate and justify.

Comment: So if it's not explicitly written, I will always take the decision to choose the equally probably case? Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at a 6x6 table, rows/col numbered 1:6. Each cell contains the value $(\text{row num:col num})$. Obviously, the table is symmetric around the main diagonal. Obviously, identical numbers appear only on the main diagonal. The total number of unique cells/pairs in the table would be
$$
\frac{6 \cdot 6 - 6}{2} + 6 = 21
$$